# MySQL instance is not accessible through local host

Tags: mysql

I ran the below command from command line

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u root -p and after entering the pass word I gave the below command.
mysql> status
```

which returned these results:

```
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.22 for Win64 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          87
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.22 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    cp850
Conn.  characterset:    cp850
TCP port:               3306
Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
Uptime:                 2 hours 11 min 59 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 1434  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 208  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 129  Queries per second avg: 0.181
```

It is showing that the MySQL server is connected at the port 3306. But when I am trying to open it through `http://localhost:3306` an error is shown and nothing is showing up.

[error during the access of MySQL server local host instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jfN9.png)

Comment: Removed the `sql-server` tag - this is **clearly** for `mysql` instead

Comment: hey guys. please help

Answer (score 0):

Stop the server and restart the service again.

```
$> sudo server mysql status

$> sudo server mysql stop

$> sudo server mysql start
$> sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld status

$> sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop

$> sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Comment: Hi Sanjoy . thanks for responding. I am using windows 10 OS. I stopped the MySQL80 service through Services and again tried the same steps as mentioned in the original question. but issues is till the same.

Comment: @Lucky are you able to connect from MySQL workbench from using the same port ?

Comment: Yes @Sanjoy, in My SQL workbench > Management > Server Status section I am able to see that it is connected to port no 3306